# Segmentation fault in capturing aligned variables in lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, memory-alignment, avx

This little code snippet segfaults with g++ 6.2.0 and clang++ 3.8.1 with:

`clang++ -std=c++11 -O3 -mavx -pthread` or `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -mavx -pthread`

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class alignas(32) AlignedObject {
public:
  float dummy[8];
};

int main() {
  while (true) {
    std::thread([](){
      AlignedObject x;
      std::cout << &x;
      std::thread([x](){
        std::cout << &x;
      }).join();
    }).join();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Looking at the disassembly, both compilers are inserting `vmovaps` instructions that are failing, suggesting that compiler-generated objects somewhere aren't being aligned properly. It works fine if `-mavx` is removed since the instruction doesn't get used anymore. Is this a compiler bug or is this code relying on undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

Alignment specifiers such as `alignas(n)` or `__attribute__((aligned(n)))` are observed only for variables with automatic storage class. However `std::function` (which is used by the lambda) is permitted (and sometimes required) to dynamically allocate the function closure, in which case alignment specifiers are ignored and only alignments up to `std::max_align_t` are guaranteed.

In conclusion, short of passing your own custom allocator to the underlying `std::function`, objects with *extended alignment* requirements cannot be safely captured by value in lambdas, and must be captured by reference. (I guess this is more a property of `std::bind` and not lambdas specifically).